# MongoDB find based on array of objects

Tags: mongodb

I have a post document like so

```
author: '828287',
content: 'xyz',
time: 88273622324
```

And my user document looks like

```
id: '345678',
name: 'John McClane',
blocked: [{
   user: '123214',
   time: 88273626362
},{
   user: '345654',
   time: 88273698678
},{
   user: '554568',
   time: 88273658858
}],
created: 127381283
```

How can I select all of the posts that are by authors whose user id is not in my `blocked` field?

EDIT: Additionally, how can I select all of the posts by authors who are blocked, but only if the time of the post is prior to the time of the block? This means blocking a user will only block future posts and existings posts will not be affected.

Comment: Can you confirm whether the `author` field in the `post` schema is `string` or `int`?

Comment: Is the `author` field of the post document supposed to match with the `id` field of the user document? What is the significance of `blocked[i].user`?

Comment: `author` field is String. Yes, the  `author` field of the post document is equal to the `id` field of the user who posted it. `blocked` is an array of users whose posts have been blocked and therefore, we do not want to select them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

map the user's blocked property (I'm assuming you can parse that to an array):

```
var blockedUsers = user.blocked.map(function (b) {
    return b.user; //if b.user is a number and author is a string then use return b.user.toString() instead
});
```

query the db...

```
db.posts.find({author: {$nin: blockedUsers}});
```

**EDIT**

Try this one out for your edit

```
var condition = user.blocked.map(function (b) {
    var aux = { $and: [ { author: b.user }, { time: {$lt: b.time} } ] };
    return aux; 
});

var blockedUsers = user.blocked.map(function (b) {
    return b.user; //if b.user is a number and author is a string then use return b.user.toString() instead
});

condition.push({ author: {$nin: blockedUsers }});

db.posts.find({$or: condition });
```

The variable `condition` ends up looking like this

```
[
    {$and: [ {author: "123214"}, {time: { $lt: 88273626362 } } ] },
    {$and: [ {author: "345654"}, {time: { $lt: 88273698678 } } ] },
    {$and: [ {author: "554568"}, {time: { $lt: 88273658858 } } ] },
    {author: {$nin: ["123214", "345654", "554568"] }}
]
```

That should help you understand the query

Comment: `blockedUsers` is an array of integers and the `author` field in the post collection (according to the OP provided schema) is of string type hence the query won't find a match.

Comment: I assume that was just an example.. but if that is the case then I would advice to normalise the type in both places. In any case I'll edit the answer to include that scenario

Comment: This is correct for the question as I had asked it, but this solution does not lend itself well to solving my next step that I did not mention. I have updated the post with the second part.

Comment: @JacobPariseau It's considered a bad habit here on SO to change questions after someone has answered. I would strongly recommend if this answered your initial question to consider marking the answer as accepted and to suggest the new direction might be better handled as a new question. For more meta details, refer to [**Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions/).

Comment: @JacobPariseau check my edit for your new requirements